# Is there a computable homeomorphism between two different Cartesian powers of the computable real numbers?

Tags: gn.general-topology, computable-analysis

It's well know that it is surprisingly difficult to prove that $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ are not homeomorphic for $n\neq m$. Commonly proofs go through Brouwer's fixed point theorem, which is 'computably false' for dimensions greater than one: let $K$ denote the computable real numbers. For $n>1$, there are computable functions from $\left( [0,1]\cap K \right)^n$ to itself with no computable fixed point.

That by itself may not seem very bad, since the function may still extend to a continuous function on $[0,1]^n$ and have an incomputable fixed point, but a corollary of this is that there is a computable retraction of $\left( [0,1]\cap K \right)^n$ onto its boundary. Such a function clearly can't be extended to a continuous function on $[0,1]^n$. So we can see that the topological behavior of $K^n$, even when restricted to computable functions, is very different from the topological behavior of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

On the other hand, $K$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ (although not computably so) and $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^m$ for any $n$ and $m$, so $K^n$ is homeomorphic to $K^m$ for any $n$ and $m$.

So the question is: Is there a computable homeomorphism between $K^n$ and $K^m$ for some $n\neq m$? If there is one I would assume we need $n,m>1$.

Comment: For context, do you know if $\mathbf{Q}$ is computably homeomorphic to $\mathbf{Q}^2$?

Comment: @YCor Yes, they are; the usual back-and-forth (with requirements) construction of a homeomorphism is totally effective.

Comment: There is a proof that $\mathbb R \not\cong \mathbb R^2$. It's effectively the usual one, with the usage of the Constructive Intermediate Value Theorem instead of the classical one

Comment: Of course, this argument implies more generally that $\mathbb R \not \cong \mathbb R^n$ for any $n > 1$

Comment: See here for the Constructive Intermediate Value Theorem: http://www.paultaylor.eu/ASD/lamcra/introivt. The usual proof is an elementary "interval trisection" argument

Comment: You might already have known this, but it's for the record

Answer (score 5):

I believe the full picture to be rather open, but Takayuki Kihara has shown that there is a computable embedding of $K^4$ into $K^3$ in

[T. Kihara: *The Brouwer invariance theorems in reverse mathematics* arXiv 2002.10715](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.10715)

The argument is outlined in the middle of p. 13. It uses Ovrekov's "constructive map of the square into itself, which moves every constructive point", from which it follows that $\mathrm{WKL}$ fails for the computable numbers. Kihara's paper then shows that for any model of $\mathbb{R}$ in which $\mathrm{WKL}$ fails, there is a topological embedding from $\mathbb{R}^m$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ for any $m$.

Whether we can even have a computable injection of $K^3$ into $K^2$ is listed as an open question here:

[http://www.math.mi.i.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~kihara/questions.html](http://www.math.mi.i.nagoya-u.ac.jp/%7Ekihara/questions.html)

Although I don't have much to go on with, I suspect that asking about mutual embeddability might be the cleaner question here compared to computable homeomorphism.

Comment: I hope someone will extract a construction from this paper for the special case of $\mathbb{R}^4$; that would be worth posting as a separate answer.