# Is the Hilbert space-filling curve bijective over computable numbers?

Tags: computability-theory, computable-analysis, space-filling-curves

The [Hilbert curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) is a continuous space-filling curve that maps $I$ to $I^n$ where $I$ denotes the unit interval [1]. Like all other space-filling curves, it is not one-to-one. I am wondering if the Hilbert curve, or a common variant thereof, becomes a continuous bijective map if we restrict its domain/range to $\mathbb{CN} \mapsto \mathbb{CN}^n$ where $\mathbb{CN} \subset I$ denotes the set of computable numbers that lie within the unit interval.

At first glance, this seems like a true statement because we have the following two algorithms [2]:

- A forward algorithm that takes any number $t \in \mathbb{CN}$ as input, iterates over its binary digits, and sequentially produces the binary digits of all numbers in a corresponding (unique) tuple $T \in \mathbb{CN}^n$.
- A reverse algorithm that takes any tuple $T \in \mathbb{CN}^n$ as input, (simultaneously) iterates over the binary digits of $T$'s elements, and sequentially produces the binary digits of a (unique) number $t \in \mathbb{CN}$.

However, I'm not sure if this simple reasoning neglects to account for any of the finer points in computable analysis, especially with respect to the curve's continuity.

[1] As Pietro Majer points out, the *original* Hilbert curve maps $I$ to $I^2$. In this question, I am referring to its standard n-dimensional extension that uses Gray codes to construct its finite approximations.

[2] The algorithms I mention above is described [here](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1751381?journalCode=apc). As far as I can tell, these algorithms operate on the standard n-dimensional Hilbert curve (and utilize Gray codes to construct outputs from given inputs).

Thanks in advance for any comments, ideas and pointers to the relevant literature.

Comment: Injectivity depends on the curve of course - maybe the original curve maps two computable points to the same element. I think the "right" question here is whether *some* Hilbert curve which is *computable* is injective on the computable points.

Comment: @NoahSchweber; You are right, being specific matters here. Even though I was talking about the specific curve whose construction was as given in the Wikipedia link, this was not clear. I will add a reference to a specific construction to clarify the question.

Comment: I believe the standard curve is **not injective on computable points** - intuitively, we can find many non-injectivities pretty easily, and this suggests that those non-injectivities are computable.

Comment: How can we construct a non-injective example? It seems to me that the standard algorithm based on Gray codes produces unique output bits for each input bit sequence. What am I missing?

Comment: For example, in this Hilbert curve: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve the midpoint $(1/2,1/2)$is the image of three different points, all computable.

Comment: The Hilbert curve is the very specific square filling curve $I\mapsto I^2$ defined via a dyadic subdivision, but what should be the definition of a "Hilbert curve" in $I^n$ , i.e a filling cube curve in dimension $n\ge3$? Hilbert does not make any mention to such a generalization, btw. There are of course  many constructions of $n$-cube filling curves (already described in the Peano's paper) but it is not clear if you refer to a precise natural generalization of Hilbert construction.

Comment: @PietroMajer: I mean the n-dimensional generalization that uses Gray codes. I added this to the question body.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: If we list finite binary approximations of $(1/2, 1/2)$ as a sequence of tuples, we get: $((0.1, 0.1), (0.10, 0.10), (0.100, 0.100), ...)$. Feeding this to the reverse algorithm, we generate the binary digits $(0.1, 0.10, 0.100, ...)$. It is actually easy to see that all further zeroes in the input sequence result in zeroes in the output sequence. Therefore, I deduce that $(1/2, 1/2)$ maps (uniquely) to $1/2$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Note that if we agree to represent a point of $I^3$ (or in general $I^n$) with a unique expansion, i.e. just merging the digits of the three coordinates: $x_1,y_1,z_1,x_2,y_2,z_2,x_3,\dots$ , then the Peano curve $I\to I^3$ comes from an extremely simple *involutory* bijection on the ternary strings $\{0,1,2\}^\mathbb{N} \to \{0,1,2\}^\mathbb{N}$; thus at least on the representing digits your conjecture it is true. Of course, passing to the quotient, one gets a non-injective curve  $I\to I^3$. Points with multiple fiber are easily characterized.

Comment: Where am I going wrong?  The number $1/2$ has more than one binary expansion.  Not only $0.10000\cdots$ but also $0.01111\cdots$.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: OK, the inverse image of $(1/2, 1/2)$ indeed converges to $1/6$ if we use the infinite expansion $0.01111\cdots$. But isn't this a special issue that only manifests for dyadic rationals? If we agree to use finite expansions for dyadic rationals (which is a subset of computable numbers), don't we end up with a one-to-one map?

Comment: @MehmetOzanKabak Yes, the issue "just" comes from dyadic rationals. No, we can't resolve this by any kind of agreement - because we cannot compute any specific binary expansion (or Gray code) from a real number. (Technically we even ought to be using signed digit expansions rather than binary...)

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/303278/15002

Comment: @Arno: I don't mean to be stubborn. I'm trying to understand the root issue as best as I can, but I fail. If we slightly modify the definition of the space-filling function to use finite binary expansions for dyadic rational values, why wouldn't we end up with a one-to-one map?

Comment: @MehmetOzanKabak We would end up with a bijection between the computable points, but the map is no longer computable, and it is no longer a space-filling curve.

Comment: @Arno: OK, I think I understand the root issue now. There is no way to "fix" forward and reverse maps simultaneously while preserving the space-filling property, regardless whether we operate in $I$ or $\mathbb{CN}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Hilbert curve, due to its fractal nature, is mapping certain subintervals of the unit interval to certain squares in the unit square. On any given resolution, we have a bijection between the subintervals we consider on that scale, and the squares we consider at that scale. The non-injectivity of the actual map then comes from the fact that the intervals intersect in at most one point, whereas the squares can have an entire line as intersection.

Given any fractal space filling curve with these properties, we can compute two distinct points in the interval that get mapped to the same point in the unit square: Pick two non-adjacent intervals that get mapped to adjacent squares, and decide that our target points will be in these. On the next scale, there have to be matching subintervals/squares, and so on. The intersections of the intervals/squares yield points which are computable relative to the original space filling curve.

We thus see that a computable Hilbert curve is a never a bijection on the computable points.

However, given the curve and a point in the square, we can follow the bijections between squares and intervals back to compute *some* point in its preimage. Hence, the inverse of a computable Hilbert curve is not a function, but it is computable as a multivalued function.

Comment: I would like to check if I understand your argument correctly. If we find a point $(x, y)$ that always lies on the boundary of multiple squares regardless of the scale, and if at least one such square maps to an interval that is disjoint from the rest; then this point should be a non-injective point. Do I understand you correctly? If so, consider the two-dimensional curve and the point $(x, y) = (0.5, 0.25)$. If I'm not missing something, this point satisfies our condition. Do you think this point is a non-injective point?

Comment: Let's go for (0.5,0.75) instead. This point belongs to the top-left square and to the top-right square on the first level. The top-left square is the image of [0;0.25] and the top-right square is the image of [0.75;1]. So (0.5,0.75) has a preimage in [0;0.25] and one in [0.75;1], so the curve definitely not injective there. Moreover, we can compute a preimage of (0.5,0.75) in each of the two intervals, so restricting to computable points doesn't change anything.